# Init array with fields injected with @Resource

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have Spring-managed app and try to access injected reources from array:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

@Service("serviceA")
class A {

    @Resource
    private HeaderLevelValidator defaultHeaderLevelValidator;

    @Resource
    private HeaderLevelValidator headerLevelValidator;

    /** Validators specific for Storefront. */
    private final Collection<HeaderLevelValidator> HEADER_BEAN_NAMES = Arrays.asList(defaultHeaderLevelValidator,
            headerLevelValidator);

    public Collection<HeaderLevelValidator> getHeaderValidators()
    {
        return HEADER_BEAN_NAMES;
    }

}
```

I try to access my list at Runtime with *getHeaderValidators()* but got list of nulls *{null, null}*. Why? What is correct way to define list of injected resources?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `HEADER_BEAN_NAMES` is being initialized before your beans are being injected.  Field injection occurs after object instantiation and initialization.  Try moving the initialization to a method annotated with [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html), or if you want to keep `HEADER_BEAN_NAMES` final, use constructor injection instead.

Comment: Well thanks but this approach has few drawbacks:
1) If I have few ctors I will need to manage it somehow; 2) If I use \@PostConstruct I will not see clear definitions of my arrays and may forget to add some new bean in that array. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @MichaelZ Just don't forget. Mark's suggestions are what you have to work with, with Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize post construction.

```
private Collection<HeaderLevelValidator> HEADER_BEAN_NAMES;

@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
   HEADER_BEAN_NAMES = Arrays.asList(defaultHeaderLevelValidator,
        headerLevelValidator);
}
```

The init() method will be called after the managed bean is constructed by Spring. Note that HEADER_BEAN_NAMES cannot be final as it is initialized post construction.

Comment: Not if the field is `final`.

Comment: Absolutely correct! Don't declare it final, or don't use @PostConstruct.